# Clustering text embeddings: TF-IDF + BERT Sentence Embeddings

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, natural-language, k-means, sparse

I am trying to cluster a few thousand forum posts that are similar in content to Stackoverfow.

So far, I have tried two main approaches to represent the posts:

1. TF-IDF
2. Sentence embedding based on BERT.

With both of them, the resulting clusters are not very coherent. It is not at all obvious as to what each cluster might be representing when I try to go through the posts cluster by cluster.

However, I did notice one rough pattern. The TF-IDF clustering is more likely to cluster the text along the lines of different *topics* being spoken about (e.g., NullPointerException, polymorphism, etc.), while the sentence embedding approach is more likely to cluster it based on the *type* and *tone* of the question (is the user asking for help, are they frustrated, are they thanking someone, etc).

While the lukewarm quality of the clustering prevents me from definitively making a statement like the above, I think it does hold true for the few dozens of clusters I've examined manually.

Now, I want to combine the representational powers of both TF-IDF as well as sentence embeddings. So I want to concatenate the two vectors for each post and try to cluster them.

However, K-means gives terrible results. Any idea on:

1. How to combine the (relatively) dense sentence embedding features and the sparse TF-IDF features for clustering (through some weighting schema, perhaps)?
2. What clustering techniques I can use for this kind of data?

Thank you!